ValueError: mismatched dimensions in reward arrays during DAgger imitation learning
I am currently trying to use the imitation library on a policy that I have generated.
I have set up my environment using gymnasium and I am loading in my policy.
And I am getting the following error:
(DPS) (base) julian@m15-R7:~/Desktop/Shallow_Lake_Problem$ /home/julian/anaconda3/envs/DPS/bin/python "/home/julian/Desktop/Shallow_Lake_Problem/attempt 1/distill.py"
Saving the dataset (1/1 shards): 100%|██████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████| 1/1 [00:00<00:00, 238.49 examples/s]
Saving the dataset (1/1 shards): 100%|██████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████| 1/1 [00:00<00:00, 257.08 examples/s]
Saving the dataset (1/1 shards): 100%|██████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████| 1/1 [00:00<00:00, 254.18 examples/s]
Saving the dataset (1/1 shards): 100%|██████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████| 1/1 [00:00<00:00, 220.73 examples/s]
Saving the dataset (1/1 shards): 100%|██████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████| 1/1 [00:00<00:00, 226.96 examples/s]
Saving the dataset (1/1 shards): 100%|██████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████| 1/1 [00:00<00:00, 190.55 examples/s]
Saving the dataset (1/1 shards): 100%|██████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████| 1/1 [00:00<00:00, 226.41 examples/s]
Saving the dataset (1/1 shards): 100%|██████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████| 1/1 [00:00<00:00, 256.02 examples/s]
Saving the dataset (1/1 shards): 100%|██████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████| 1/1 [00:00<00:00, 273.08 examples/s]
Saving the dataset (1/1 shards): 100%|██████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████| 1/1 [00:00<00:00, 226.14 examples/s]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/julian/Desktop/Shallow_Lake_Problem/attempt 1/distill.py", line 87, in <module>
    dagger_trainer.extend_and_update(bc_train_kwargs=None)
  File "/home/julian/anaconda3/envs/DPS/lib/python3.10/site-packages/imitation/algorithms/dagger.py", line 499, in extend_and_update
    self._try_load_demos()
  File "/home/julian/anaconda3/envs/DPS/lib/python3.10/site-packages/imitation/algorithms/dagger.py", line 442, in _try_load_demos
    transitions, num_demos = self._load_all_demos()
  File "/home/julian/anaconda3/envs/DPS/lib/python3.10/site-packages/imitation/algorithms/dagger.py", line 413, in _load_all_demos
    demo_transitions = rollout.flatten_trajectories(self._all_demos)
  File "/home/julian/anaconda3/envs/DPS/lib/python3.10/site-packages/imitation/data/rollout.py", line 579, in flatten_trajectories
    cat_parts = {
  File "/home/julian/anaconda3/envs/DPS/lib/python3.10/site-packages/imitation/data/rollout.py", line 580, in <dictcomp>
    key: types.concatenate_maybe_dictobs(part_list)
  File "/home/julian/anaconda3/envs/DPS/lib/python3.10/site-packages/imitation/data/types.py", line 224, in concatenate_maybe_dictobs
    return np.concatenate(arrs)
ValueError: all the input arrays must have same number of dimensions, but the array at index 0 has 2 dimension(s) and the array at index 55 has 1 dimension(s)

Based on the trace of the error, it appears that it is related to generating the demonstration trajectories. So I believed that it would have been related to my expert policy since that's generating the demonstration trajectories.
I am currently ensuring that all observations, rewards, and actions are all 1-D arrays to avoid this error.
from my environment file:
import gym
from gymnasium import spaces
import numpy as np
from LakeProblem import *
from lake_agent import *

class LakeEnv(gym.Env):
    """Custom Lake Environment that follows gym.Env"""
    metadata = {'render_modes': ['None']}

    def __init__(self, n_years=nYears, q=q, b=b, alpha=alpha, delta=delta,
                 inertia_threshold=-inertia_threshold, reliability_threshold=reliability_threshold):
        super(LakeEnv, self).__init__()

        # Define action and observation space with explicit shape=(1,) for actions
        self.action_space = spaces.Box(low=np.array([0.01]), high=np.array([0.1]), shape=(1,), dtype=np.float32)
        self.observation_space = spaces.Box(low=0.0, high=2.0, shape=(1,), dtype=np.float32)

        # Initialize the DPS expert policy
        self.expert_policy = DPSExpertPolicy(C, R, W, self.observation_space, self.action_space)

        # Initialize environment parameters
        self.n_years = n_years
        self.q = q
        self.b = b
        self.alpha = alpha
        self.delta = delta
        self.inertia_threshold = inertia_threshold
        self.reliability_threshold = reliability_threshold
        self.lake_state = 0.0  # Initial phosphorus concentration
        self.year = 0

    def step(self, learner_action):
        # Clip the learner's action to stay within bounds and handle as 1D action
        learner_action = np.clip(learner_action, 0.01, 0.1).reshape(-1)  # Ensure action is 1D

        # Calculate lake dynamics
        P_recycling = ((self.lake_state ** self.q) / (1 + self.lake_state ** self.q))
        natural_inflow = np.random.lognormal(mean=mu, sigma=sigma)
        next_lake_state = self.lake_state * (1 - self.b) + P_recycling + learner_action + natural_inflow
        next_lake_state = np.clip(next_lake_state, self.observation_space.low[0], self.observation_space.high[0])

        # Calculate reward based on imitation accuracy
        expert_action = self.expert_policy.predict(np.array([self.lake_state], dtype=np.float32))[0]  # Ensure 1D
        reward = float(-abs(learner_action - expert_action))

        # Update the lake state
        self.lake_state = next_lake_state

        # Check if the environment should terminate
        self.year += 1
        terminated = self.year >= self.n_years

        # Return 1D observation
        obs = np.array([self.lake_state], dtype=np.float32).reshape(-1)
        reward = np.array(reward).reshape(-1)  # Ensure 1D reward
        return obs, reward, terminated, False, {}

    def reset(self, seed=None, options=None):
        """Reset the environment to an initial state."""
        super().reset(seed=seed)

        # Reset environment variables
        self.lake_state = 0  # Initial lake phosphorus concentration
        self.year = 0

        # Return 1D observation
        obs = np.array([self.lake_state], dtype=np.float32).reshape(-1)
        return obs, {}


from my expert policy file:
import numpy as np
from LakeProblem import RBFpolicy
import pickle

# Load the RBF parameters generated in DPS.py
with open('rbf_params.pkl', 'rb') as f:
    C, R, W = pickle.load(f)

# Create a class for the DPS expert policy using the RBF function
class DPSExpertPolicy:
    def __init__(self, C, R, W, observation_space, action_space):
        self.C = C
        self.R = R
        self.W = W
        self.observation_space = observation_space
        self.action_space = action_space

    def predict(self, obs):
        # Ensure obs is a NumPy array
        obs = np.array(obs).reshape(1,)

        # Extract lake state from 1D observation array
        lake_state = obs[0]  # Since obs is 1D, take the first element

        # Calculate action using the RBF policy
        action = RBFpolicy(lake_state, self.C, self.R, self.W)

        # Ensure the action is returned as a 1D array
        return np.array([action]), None  # Return 1D action array

    def __call__(self, obs, state=None, dones=None):
        """Make the class callable and accept extra arguments."""
        actions, state = self.predict(obs)
        return actions, state

I then try to use the imitation package:
import gymnasium as gym
from gymnasium.wrappers import FlattenObservation
from imitation.algorithms import dagger, bc
from imitation.data import rollout
from stable_baselines3.common.vec_env import DummyVecEnv
from imitation.data.wrappers import RolloutInfoWrapper
import numpy as np
import pickle
import sys

# Redirect terminal output to a text file
sys.stdout = open('output_log.txt', 'w')

from lake_agent import DPSExpertPolicy

# Load the RBF parameters generated in DPS.py
with open('rbf_params.pkl', 'rb') as f:
    C, R, W = pickle.load(f)

# Register the custom environment
gym.register(
    id='LakeEnv-v1',
    entry_point='lake_env:LakeEnv',
    max_episode_steps=100,
)

# Create a vectorized environment
n_envs = 1  # Number of parallel environments
rng = np.random.default_rng(42)  # Create a random number generator

lake_env = DummyVecEnv([lambda: RolloutInfoWrapper(FlattenObservation(gym.make("LakeEnv-v1"))) for _ in range(n_envs)])

# Instantiate the expert policy
expert_policy = DPSExpertPolicy(
    C, R, W,
    observation_space=lake_env.observation_space,
    action_space=lake_env.action_space
)

# Set up BC (Behavior Cloning) trainer with RNG
bc_trainer = bc.BC(
    observation_space=lake_env.observation_space,
    action_space=lake_env.action_space,
    rng=rng  # Provide the rng keyword argument here
)

# Set up DAgger with RNG
dagger_trainer = dagger.SimpleDAggerTrainer(
    venv=lake_env,
    expert_policy=expert_policy,
    bc_trainer=bc_trainer,
    rng=rng,  # Pass the random number generator here
    scratch_dir="dagger_scratch"
)

# Step 1: Collect expert demonstrations for round 0
print("Collecting expert demonstrations...")
collector = dagger_trainer.create_trajectory_collector()

sample_until = rollout.make_sample_until(min_timesteps=1000)  # Set minimum timesteps for demo collection
    
rollouts = rollout.generate_trajectories(
    policy=expert_policy,
    venv=collector,
    sample_until=sample_until,
    rng=rng,
)

# Step 2: Proceed with DAgger training after collecting demonstrations
total_timesteps = 50000
timesteps_collected = 0

while timesteps_collected < total_timesteps:
    rollouts = rollout.rollout(
        policy=dagger_trainer.policy,
        venv=lake_env,
        sample_until=sample_until,
        rng=rng  # Provide the rng argument here
    )
    # Ensure bc_train_kwargs is either None or a dictionary
    dagger_trainer.extend_and_update(bc_train_kwargs=None)
    timesteps_collected += sum(len(traj) for traj in rollouts)

# Save the trained learner policy
dagger_trainer.policy.save("learner_policy")

print("Learner policy saved to 'learner_policy'")

# Close the file
sys.stdout.close()

and I get the error above. I am not sure what is causing the mismatch between dimensions.
